# Why is Iron (Fe) difficult to reduce?

Tags: redox, transition-metals, periodic-trends

1. $\ce{Fe^3+ + e- -> Fe^2+} \quad +0.77$
2. $\ce{Fe^3+ + 3e- -> Fe} \quad -0.04$
3. $\ce{Fe^2+ + 2e- -> Fe} \quad -0.41$
4. $\ce{Zn^2+ + 2e- -> Zn} \quad -0.76$
5. $\ce{Co^2+ + 2e- -> Co} \quad -0.29$
6. $\ce{Ni^2+ + 2e- -> Ni} \quad -0.25$

I am having a hard time to understand if there is a trend in reduction potentials so predictions could be made on whether a certain 'strong' (e.g. $\ce{NaBH4}$) or 'weak' (e.g. hydrogen) reductant  reduces an iron salt. I also wonder if there is a trend in the periodic table between first row d metals.

My question is possibly best split into two: Is there a trend in the periodic table regarding reduction potentials? Why is iron (our of the first row elements) so hard to reduce compared to others?

Comment: Fe is not all that hard to reduce compared to others from that row. Zn is harder to reduce, and Ti even worse.

Comment: That's true. So is there no trend in the first row as to why that occurs?

Comment: There is no "that" in the first place. As to the trend... well, it is kinda possible to derive certain qualitative trends, but $\ce{Fe^2+}$ is in no way exceptional.